# vue-resource.common.js:1099 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, node.js

I try to build vuejs project and I will deploy my project in my server, but when I run on my server I get the following error:

```
vue-resource.common.js:1099 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)t.json @ vue-resource.common.js:1099(anonymous function) @ app.fe8052b….js:248
```

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error

Comment: Response.prototype.json = function json() {
        return JSON.parse(this.body);
};

Comment: HTML is being received instead of JSON. You should check the `Content-Type` header first before parsing as JSON.